# Sci-Fi Drama TV Series about telepathy between an alien and a boy

Tags: tv, aliens, story-identification, telepathy

I'm trying to remember this show, 80's or early 90's, about a boy who receives telepathic messages from an alien, and his family thinks he's going crazy. All very serious and dark. The only thing I remember are the credits and cuts to commercials: they show the protagonist's head over an eerie landscape, spinning very slowly and fading into an alien's egg or something.

The name of the show was the name of the boy, very simple, one word... Ben, or Max, or anything like that.

Comment: Was it live action or animated?

Answer (score 12):

*Chocky*, a 1984 UK live-action, seems to *somewhat* fit this.  From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocky_%28TV_series%29#Series_synopses):

> **Chocky:**  Matthew Gore is an intelligent boy chosen by a mysterious extraterrestrial visitor to be a source of information about life on Earth. As his schoolwork and artistic talent improve dramatically he arouses the suspicion of powerful groups who wish to tap into the amazing fund of knowledge to which he is now party.
>
> **Chocky's Children:** A year has passed since Matthew said goodbye to his alien friend, and in the summer holidays he meets Albertine, a mathematical prodigy, with whom he discovers he can communicate telepathically. One day Chocky returns to warn him that they are both in danger. When he returns to tell Albertine, he finds she has disappeared.
>
> **Chocky's Challenge:**
>   Chocky, an invisible being from another world, has come into Matthew's life. His powerful knowledge has aroused a great deal of interest from the military, and they are willing to take drastic action if they don't get what they want.

While I didn't find a general synopsis of the show as a whole, this is one from same-titled [John Wyndham book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocky#Plot_summary) that the show was based on:

> Many children have imaginary friends but one father becomes rather concerned that his son, Matthew, is a bit old to have one. His concerns deepen as his son becomes increasingly distressed and blames it on arguments with this unseen companion. As the story unfolds, it becomes clear that the friend is far from imaginary, but is an alien consciousness communicating with Matthew's mind—a fact that is of intense interest to shadowy government forces. Chocky reveals that it is a scout sent from its home planet (where there is only one sex) in search of new planets to colonise. Chocky, talking "through" Matthew, to his father, David Gore, explains that in saving Matthew from a recent accident it has violated the rules of its scout mission (interfering with events on Earth) and must end its link with him completely. Its further work on Earth will be conducted in a much more covert manner.

What makes this a likely suspect is the intro sequence, with rotating boy's head, as was mentioned in the question body:

Spielberg's had the [option](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/dreamworks-picks-up-chocky-rights-119807) on this for a while.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This has been haunting me for life.....